# CSS flex box within a flex box child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a panel which uses display: flex to have a fixed size header and then a content div filling the rest of the panels height (the panel could be any height).
That works fine.

Inside the content div I want the same thing but in reverse. This time however, the content div contains a bunch of content (let's say text for simplicity). This content div should behave as follows:

- It should expand to fill the parent div if the content is small
- It should overflow scroll if the content is too big

Currently I can't figure out how to do either.

Here is a demonstration of the problem:

```css
div {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}

#panel {
  height:150px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

#title {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#chat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}

#chatmessages {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#chatbox {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
<div id="title">
Panel title
</div>
<div id="content">

<div id="chat">
<div id="chatmessages">
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
</div>
<div id="chatbox">
<input value="this will be a chat box" />
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wh5sq6fw/7/

And attached is an image of what I want to achieve in the 2 cases

I hope this is clear enough, let me know if there is anything I can clarify

Thanks
[image: When content is too small]
[image: When content is too big]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>The `#content`, `#chat`, `#chatmessages` need a height, and</strike> I removed the `#content` div and a couple of rules/properties and added `overflow: auto` to `#chatmessages`

```css
div {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}
#panel {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
#chat {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#chatmessages {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <div id="title">
    Panel title
  </div>
  <div id="chat">
    <div id="chatmessages">
      <div>Hello World</div>
      <div>Hello World</div>
      <div>Hello World</div>
      <div>Hello World</div>
      <div>Hello World</div>
      <div>Hello World</div>
      <div>Hello World</div>
      <div>Hello World</div>
      <div>Hello World</div>
      <div>Hello World</div>
      <div>Hello World</div>
    </div>
    <div id="chatbox">
      <input value="this will be a chat box" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you have to have the `#content`, it needs `display: flex; flex: 1;`

```css
div {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}
#panel {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
#content, #chat {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#chatmessages {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <div id="title">
    Panel title
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="chat">
      <div id="chatmessages">
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
      </div>
      <div id="chatbox">
        <input value="this will be a chat box" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
This is close, but as you can see the inner box (the blue one) is flowing outside of the red box. It needs to fit inside

Comment: @MatthewShaile Updated ... cleaned up code a little, it was the unnecessary `#content` div that needed to be removed for the `flex: 1` properties to work as they suppose to

Answer (score 1):

I believe you overcomplicated your markup. Here it is, simplified a bit:

```css
#panel {
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}
#panel>* {
  flex-grow:0;
}
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
#content > div {
  min-height: min-content;
  display: flex;
}
#chatbox input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <div id="title">
    Panel title
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div>Hello World</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
   <div>Hello World</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
   <div>Hello World</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
   <div>Hello World</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
   
    
  </div>
  <div id="chatbox">
    <input value="this will be a chat box" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Your `#content` doesn't shrink because its children do not have a `height`. To give them height without hardcoding it, use `min-height:min-content` and... *voilà*.

Flexible layout, *title* and *chatbox* taking the space they need, *messages* always filling the rest and overflowing with scroll when too tall.

---

And this is the version with your (unnecessarily complex IMHO) markup:

```css
#panel {
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
#title {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}
#panel>* {
  flex-grow:0;
}
#panel * {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#content, #chat, #content, #chatmessages {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#chatmessages {
  overflow: auto;
}
#chatmessages > div {
  min-height: min-content;
  display: flex;
}
#chatbox input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <div id="title">
    Panel title
  </div>
  <div id="content">

    <div id="chat">
      <div id="chatmessages">
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
      </div>
      <div id="chatbox">
        <input value="this will be a chat box" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The markup must be that way. The panel is a reusable component and the contents varies

Comment: @MatthewShaile see second snippet, streamlined all flex pushers you'll need with minimum amount of code (i think :). Take care.

Comment: Thanks for entertaining my "unnecessary markup". I promise in the real world scenario it is entirely necessary, and you've solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Quite welcome. Anytime. Don't forget to [`prefix`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) :).

Answer (score 0):

Just add overflow: auto; to your "panel".

```css
div {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}

#panel {
  height:150px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

#title {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#chat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}

#chatmessages {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#chatbox {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
<div id="title">
Panel title
</div>
<div id="content">

<div id="chat">
<div id="chatmessages">
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
</div>
<div id="chatbox">
<input value="this will be a chat box" />
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,
This isn't what the image shows, because the chat input box isn't visible at all times. Only the messages should scroll.